# Gradle project sync failed, how to setup proxy configuration?

Tags: android

I cloned the repo from GitHub.
In Andriod Studio, this image appears

[image]
It also shows

```
Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2
```

and
[image]

I checked JAVA_HOME

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin
```

Event Log
[image]

How to set proxies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by choosing Settings->Apperances & Behaviour -> System Settings > HTTP Proxy
NO Proxy button.
Then in my .gradle file uncommented proxy lines.